# conditionally delete numbers from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two types of Strings like the following :

```
78:24207 PERF keytouchListAction ProtocolSelect 04.00 : 1502876877199 1502876879180
```

or

```
78:27247 PERF create tab state : 1502876879180
```

I'm looking for a regex to delete the numbers at the start of the string `78:24207`

to produice something like this :

```
PERF keytouchListAction ProtocolSelect 04.00 : 1502876877199 1502876879180
```

or

```
PERF create tab state : 1502876879180
```

and then if the string containt two numbers after the `:` take only the first number :

```
PERF keytouchListAction ProtocolSelect 04.00 : 1502876877199 1502876879180
```

becomes :

```
PERF keytouchListAction ProtocolSelect 04.00 : 1502876877199
```

I've tried this `replace(/^\d+\.\s*/, '');` for the first pattern but does't seem to work.

and this pattern for the second problem `replace(\:.*$)` but nothing changed in my string.

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Why the downvote? OP explains the issue, and shows effort.

Comment: Use something like https://regex101.com/ for regex testing, as creating the regex `^(\d+\:\d+\s)` was quite simple. --- You may not even need the capture group...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative: don't replace - get the wanted content with `match` using

```
[a-z].*:\s*\d+
```

It matches a letter and everything after it up to a colon, followed by (optional space and) a number.

```js
document.write(
    '78:24207 PERF keytouchListAction ProtocolSelect 04.00 : 1502876877199 1502876879180'
    .match(/[a-z].*:\s*\d+/i)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a single `replace` call:

```js
var s = '78:24207 PERF keytouchListAction ProtocolSelect 04.00 : 1502876877199 1502876879180'
var r = s.replace(/^\d+:\d+\s*|(:\s*\d+)\s+\d+$/g, '$1')

console.log(r)

s = '78:27303 PERF tab state created : 1502882663195'
var r = s.replace(/^\d+:\d+\s*|(:\s*\d+)\s+\d+$/g, '$1')

console.log(r)
```

Comment: this is worked for the second  problem but I still get the numbers at the start of the string  `78:27303 PERF tab state created :  1502882663195`

Comment: `78:27303 PERF tab state created : 1502882663195` is becoming `PERF tab state created : 1502882663195` as you can see in my updated demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it by first matching and then replacing like in the code snippet

```js
function matchAndReplace(str){
 str = str.match(/\d+:\d+ ([\w\s.]*)(:\s*\d+)/g)[0];
 console.log(str.replace(/^\d+:\d+ /,''));
}
matchAndReplace("78:24207 PERF keytouchListAction ProtocolSelect 04.00 : 1502876877199 1502876879180");
matchAndReplace("78:27247 PERF create tab state : 1502876879180");
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first pattern you need:

```
replace(/^\d+:\d+\s+/, '');
```

For the second pattern:

```
replace(/(\s+\d+)\s+\d+$/, '$1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you care about the pattern? If not you can just replace first 9 characters using this:

```
 var str = "78:27247 PERF create tab state : 1502876879180";
 var res = str.replace(/^.{9}/, "");
 console.log(res);
```